# Curvature forms of holomorphic line bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hermitian-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold, $L$ a holomorphic line bundle over $M$, and $\nabla$ a connection extending the holomorphic structure map $\overline{\partial}$ of $L$. In general can it happen that the curvature form has a $(2,0)$ component? In the case that it does not, can the $(1,1)$-curvature form be non-degenerate?

Comment: It certainly can contain a $(2,0)$-component. In general, if $\theta$ is the connection matrix in a local frame, then the curvature is $\Theta=d\theta+\theta^2=d\theta$ (since $\theta$ is a $1$-form). Locally, the connection matrix could be any $1$-form, and if it is compatible with $\bar\partial$, it could be any $(1,0)$-form.

Comment: Regarding your second question, it seems like the Chern connection associated to a hermitian metric on $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ would answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, any closed 2-form $\eta$ with integer cohomology
can serve as the curvature of a connection
on a line bundle. This can be seen if you take a line bundle with
the same Chern class and connection $\nabla$
(which is possible using the $C^\infty$ exponential
sequence) and modifying the connection by taking
$\nabla_1:=\nabla +\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a 1-form
such that $d\alpha= \eta-\eta_0$, where $\eta_0$ is
the curvature of $\nabla$. If your form $\eta$
was of type (1,1)+(2,0), the resulting connection
$\nabla_1$ induces a holomorphic structure on $L$.
The (1,1)-part of the curvature can be non-degenerate,
degenerate or even zero.